# It struck from me a sudden, springing dislike?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading *The Song of Achilles* and don't understand what 'struck from' means here (chapter three):

> It struck from me a sudden, springing dislike.

Who is feeling the dislike here? I only know of the expression 'strike someone as'.

Comment: The narrator of Madeline Miller's novel (Patroclus) has experienced something that struck from (produced in) him a sudden, springing dislike.

Comment: To be clear, this is a poetic and non-standard usage (in keeping with Homer's colorful turns of phrase). "From" is an odd choice for describing emotions, and "springing" as a participle only barely makes when describing an emotion. The sentence deftly and intuitively combines more awkward sentences like "It caused a sudden dislike to spring up in me" and "It struck up in me a sudden dislike."

Comment: There is also the idiom *strike a chord in/with* "to strongly impress (someone)" e.g., *Her comments about political corruption clearly struck a chord with many voters.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strike%20a%20chord%20in)

Comment: @AndyBonner: This is non-standard only in the sense that it is evocative prose. It's not the way people talk in a bar, say, but it is not at all out of place between the covers of a novel—at least not a literary one.

Comment: I read "struck from me" in this sense as being analogous to "striking a spark from a flint". The "sudden springing dislike" is certainly generated within the speaker but comes from their own being, metaphorically like the spark being struck from the body of the flint.